# How to change a label in GUI repeatedly(often)?

Tags: python-2.7, pygtk

Will i have to create a new window everytime this label changes or can i just edit when it needs to. I have a program that keeps track of the things they get right and the total `total`
and `current_score` in a GUI. for example `label = Gtk.Label("you have %s out of %s", current_score, total` the user will input something to check if it is right and if it is it will add to the `current_score` and `total`. Is there a way to do it??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if I understood correctly, anyhow:

```
label = Gtk.Label("some text")
label.set_text("some other text")
```

http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/api/Gtk_3.0/classes/Label.html#Gtk.Label.set_text